# Locally free modules

Tags: modules, deformation-theory, reference-request

Consider M a locally free $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{n}}$-module. does exist a theory of deformation for that type of object? I would like to know, which conditions has to satisfy the total space of a one (but also higher) parameter deformation of M in such way that each fiber is locally free.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what definition of "deformation" you are using?  (In my world, the Hecke algebra is a very interesting deformation of the group algebra of a complex reflection group which is nonetheless "trivial" according to the "infinitesimal" point of view).

Comment: What I have in mind is the following type of situation:consider $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ with variables $x_1, \dots, x_n,t$ and X an $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{n+1}}$-module such that when t=0 I get M, I would like to know what I sould expact from X if for each fixed t, X restrict to a locally free module.I mention deformations because, I'm deforming a geometrical object and I can attach to it the module M, and so I think that deforming my object I'm also deforming M in some sense...Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks!  You're really thinking about "global" deformations.  I'm not an expert, just wanted to understand the question better.

Answer (score 4):

I think the theory you are looking for can be found in Th. 8.5.3, chap. 8 (p. 210) of 
the book by B. Fantechi et al., "FGA explained".